# Select rows with more than one occurrence but not group them

Tags: mysql

I have an IP table with users IP addresses stored. I basically want to see if potentially a user has created more than one profile.

How can I select rows from the table where the IP address shows more than once, but also not group them so I can see the user ids for each IP?

I have this so far but I can't figure out a way to find duplicate IPs without grouping:

```
SELECT ow_base_user.username, ow_userip_address.userid,     ow_userip_address.ip, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM ow_userip_address
INNER JOIN ow_base_user ON ow_userip_address.userid = ow_base_user.id
GROUP BY ip
HAVING cnt > 1
```

Comment: try this (select count(*) from ow_userip_address where ow_userip_address.ip ) > 1

Comment: Then remove `GROUP By ip`.

Comment: This just returned all rows with an extra column showing '1' in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT ow_base_user.username, ow_userip_address.userid, ow_userip_address.ip, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM ow_userip_address
INNER JOIN ow_base_user ON ow_userip_address.userid = ow_base_user.id
GROUP BY ip, userip_address.userid
HAVING cnt > 1
```

Comment: This sadly returned zero rows.

Comment: Basically, you want to count the number of rows which has same userid and ip? Right?

Comment: I want to return all IP addresses which show more than once, but display them all so I can see the username and userid assigned with it. This will help in identifying who may have more than one profile.